# Dynamically create a treeview in windows phone 8 from Json data

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, treeview, expander, collectionviewsource

I am trying to create a Treeview dynamically in Windows Phone 8 from the json response from my server. This json response is nested to nested [like a question asked in stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096664/dynamically-create-a-treeview) I am very confused what approach me should use, i have deseriazlied my json object but how and where to map on xaml page ? Please suggest me what Data Structure should me use Treeview / ExpanderView / CollectionViewSource or any other Data Sturcture. My json is like following

```
>Peter
    - - >user1
    - - >user2
    - - >user3
         - - >userPassword
         - - >userId
              - - > Regional
              - - > Zonal
         - - >permission
>john
>david
>Jack
    - - >user1
    - - >user2
         - - >userpassword
         - - >userId
         - - >Permissions

>Laura 
    - - > admin
    - - > permissions
          -- > user1
          -- > user2
               - - >userpassword
               - - >userId
               - - >Permissions           
                    - - > Admin
                    - - > SuperAdmin
>...
>...
>...
```

Comment: This are in wpf , might help to get idea , This is not a direct answer [Wpf refernece](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190169/how-to-create-dynamic-treeview-with-parent-child-from-database-wpf) [Wpf reference 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)

Comment: i have seen the liks you given but Not helped! :(